# What are the requirements of these Steam specific achievements?

Tags: steam, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Most of the hidden achievements in KoA seem to resolve themselves through normal game play (defeat this guy, complete on hard, etc) so I imagine the answer to this one is going to be along the same lines.

According to the lists of [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/KingdomsofAmalurReckoning/achievements/), [Xbox360](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/achievements/) and [PS3](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/trophies/) achievements these 5 are specific to Steam.

- Exterminator
- Give Her a Hand
- Keep on Rising
- Manic Pixie Dream Elf
- Message in a Bottle

What are the requirements of these 5 achievements? (I should note that Steam shows 0.1% of players have achieved them, so they are being awarded.)

Comment: @Ravendreamer The achievements might be different between the steam and Xbox360 versions, which is why I tagged this for steam.

Comment: I just checked the achievements on Xbox360Achievements.org, and I don't see this one listed, so definitely Steam specific.

Comment: Does it not show up under the in-game achievement menu? (It may be listed as *secret*, but I doubt it simply doesn't exist)

Comment: According to http://steamcommunity.com/stats/KingdomsofAmalurReckoning/achievements/ it does exist or did you mean that it most likely does exist on xbox360? @RavenDreamer

Comment: @Raven Here's the list I was using (it includes Secret achievements): http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/achievements/

Comment: @Adeese But did they actually remove some achievements from the *in-game* achievement tracker? (I forgot about the 1k point limit). Even if it's secret, the square still *exists*, so we should just be able to count squares and compare.

Comment: @Raven Didn't realize there is an in-game tracker that is different than the official ones. I have it on 360, will try to remember to check it when I play tonight.

Comment: @RavenDreamer, I checked my Xbox 360 version, and I couldn't find any in-game achievement tracker that listed this as an option.  It's also not listed on the [PS3 trophy list](http://www.ps3trophies.org/game/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/trophies/) so at least based on what I know at this point, it seems to be PC/Steam specific.

Comment: Interesting. The in-game achievement menu lists only 50 achievements. Steam itself lists 55 achievements. In that case, I'd suggest the OP be updated to include all 5 of the steam-specific achievements.

Comment: @Raven I don't see any in-game achievement list on 360. Maybe that's only in the Steam version?

Comment: @Adeese I talked with Agent86. It's on the Xbox menu, and there are 50.

Comment: @RavenDreamer A good suggestion, I'll make that edit in the morning.

Comment: @Raven Oh, I thought you meant within the game itself, not in the Guide menu. That list is the same as on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "general" requirements for these 5 achievements are (According to [Giant Bomb's achievement list](http://www.giantbomb.com/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/61-30330/achievements/?sgid=4184&sort=rarity)):

- Message in a Bottle - Located all eight message bottles in Gallows End.
- Keep on Rising - Gravehal Keep has been fully restored.
- Give Her a Hand - Found Aubrey Gilcrest's severed hand.
- Manic Pixie Dream Elf - Wooed Rast Brattigan.
- Exterminator - Killed 50 Scavs.

I'm assuming these are related to specific quests in the game, but I haven't encountered these quests yet, so I don't have more detail than this.